# Copy Files Created Today from Multiple Directories into a Single Folder

Tags: date, copy, xcopy, robocopy

I'm trying to copy files from multiple subfolders into a single folder without re-creating the subfolders in the destination folder.   I have a command that will do this, however, the problem that I have is this is something that I need to run daily as new files are created.   So I don't want to re-copy the files from the previous day.   I only need to copy files that are created on the current day.   The command that I am using is:

for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b /s /a-d "e:\testfrom" ') do @copy "%a" "e:\testto"

This does copy everything that is in the testfrom folder and puts it into the testto folder.
How can I get this to copy files in the testfrom folder that are created on the current day?

Thanks!!